# grails cobertura findAllBy

Tags: grails, automated-tests, cobertura, findall

I have grails 2.4.4 and Cobertura as covert test.
I have code like:

```
lstPerspectives = Perspectives.findAllByDbAndSysDelete(dbInstance, new Long(0))
```

But Cobertura don´t pass the test because don´t search in my DB, How can I pass this line?, How can overwrite this value? I send this lstPerspectives  but it don´t take it.

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: Have you added a `Perspectives` to the database with the given `db` and `sysDelete` at the start of the test, maybe in the spock setup or given block?

Comment: I added Perspectives ti @Mock. It´s enough?

Comment: It depends on your requirements, I'll add an example below..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor

@TestFor(Perspectives)
@Mock([Perspectives])
class PerspectivesSpec 
{
    void "test Perspectives"(){
        given:
            def dbInstance = 'aDbInstance' // don't know what this is
            def sysDelete = false // is this a boolean?
            new Perspectives( dbInstance: dbInstance, sysDelete: sysDelete ).save( failOnError: true )
        when:
            // run you bit of code that executes the snippet in your question
        then:
             // check your desired outcome
    }
}
```

I don't know if you are testing your Perspectives class directly here or something else, controller, service? so had to make a few assumptions.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem persists. I use "perspectives.Save(flush:true)" or only .save() , but it said that:

Connected to the target VM, address: 127.0.'.........', transport: 'socket'

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.snt............Save() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: save(), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map), wait(), last(), any()

 at PerspectiveController.Test the save action returns the correct model(PerspectiveController.groovy:227)

WARN   warn, Cannot unbind session, there's no SessionHolder registered

Comment: Need to see your whole test/project really, can you make it available in github?